# How to enable 5.1 channel playback on a Realtek ALC887-VD chip?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, realtek

I have an ASUS F2A55-M LE board which includes a Realtek ALC887-VD chip. Stereo audio playback works just fine but I have a 5.1 speaker set that I would like to use. I am able to achieve full surround playback in Windows 10 using the same machine but I can't seem to get it working within Ubuntu 16.04.

I've tried setting `default-sample-channels = 6` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` but even after rebooting it doesn't make a difference. Playback is still only two channels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to changing `default-sample-channels` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`, it was also necessary to launch `alsamixer` and change the number of channels to 6:

[image]

*Note: you may need to restart between changing `daemon.conf` and using `alsamixer`.*