# Trying to fix front i/o headphone out overriding audio line out

Tags: 20.04, headphones, speakers, io

I just started running Ubuntu 20.04, MATE 1.24.0 on my desktop. my case has a front i/o with audio out and microphone in, and I typically use these for my razer headset with a headset/microphone splitter.

On the rear i/o panel audio out I have a set of (stereo) speakers plugged in. Now, on Windows I haven't had any issues switching these outputs, but in Ubuntu it seems like the headphone out is taking over any time it's plugged in, regardless of what output I have selected from the drop down in sound settings.

Now I don't really mind unplugging the headphones to get the speakers to work, but it would be nice if there were a solution that could resolve the issue.

So to clarify and simplify: speakers in the rear i/o work fine when the headphones in the front panel i/o are unplugged, but the output defaults to headphones when they're plugged in, regardless of settings.

Anybody out there know where I'm going wrong here? Thanks in advance!

- motherboard chipset: Intel® Z490
- motherboard audio: Realtek® ALC887 8-Channel High Definition Audio CODEC

Comment: Have you checked your sound card settings?

Comment: @ZeissIkon i don't have a sound card installed, so as far as i know i don't have any sound card settings, unless i'm missing something here.

Comment: If you have sound output, you have a "sound card" though in desktop and laptop computers these are often integrated in the motherboard chipset.  You'll still have sound settings in that case (this is what I have, and the settings are much like they were when I had a discrete sound card many years ago, because it's the same hardware).

Comment: @ZeissIkon gotcha. that makes sense. are you just referring to the sound preferences menu, or is there somewhere else i should be looking?

Comment: For some sound hardware (drivers) there is an additional settings area for hardware settings, like how you want to handle front and rear speakers, and most importantly, what to do with the rear speakers when something's plugged into the front jack.

Comment: @ZeissIkon yeah, see i'm not finding anything like that. is that driver something i can or should locate and install or would that already be taken care of during the initial operating system install?

Comment: If you have sound, you have the driver -- but it's possible some drivers don't have this hardware control panel.  You might try to find out exactly what sound chip(set) you have in your desktop machine and edit it into your question; it'll help people answer.

Comment: @ZeissIkon yeah, that's what i assumed. appreciate the help.

Comment: I found this in the forum.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240632/5-1-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-with-3-3-5mm-jacks-allows-stereo-onlly  It seems related to your issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alsamixer: howto disable auto-mute mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131857/alsamixer-howto-disable-auto-mute-mode)

Comment: @user68186 i had actually just found this solution a few minutes ago! real facepalm moment, because basically i just didn't scroll over enough in alsamixer to see and test all of the settings.

Comment: @user68186 well the answer is already out there anyway, so i don't think it particularly matters if this post stays up or not ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED (mostly)](https://askubuntu.com/a/282640/1411455)

Turning off *automute* in alsamixer sends the audio signal to both ports simultaneously and you can then use the mixer to mute one or the other.